# Display selected image from input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, input

my question is how to display the selected file image from the input file in img tag, I have described the code below.

```
<img src="" width="200" height="100">
<input type="file" name="logo" id="upload-logo" />

$('#upload-logo').on('change', function(){
    let logo = $(this).val();
    $('img').attr('src', logo);
});
```

but the result I got after changing the src attribute is: Not allowed to load local resource: file: /// C: /fakepath/Capture.PNG, and photos are not displayed

I do not want to use ajax

Comment: this answers the question perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the file reader to validate and allow preview of the uploaded image. the browser disallows the access to local system files for good reason and the file inputs place files in a temporary folder system that the browser is allowed to access.

Here is an example of how to use the File Reader [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

```
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // do something with the result
        var file = reader.result || e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is what I expected.